# Multiple developers working in one shelveset

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015, merge, shelveset

I want to ask if it is possible and how, to work in one shelveset for multiple developers. We have to refactor lot of code but also maintain old version. We are deciding to use tfs shelvesets for this.

I´m curious if it is possible that for example two developers are simultaneously working on same task changing own shelveset and than check-in and merge to some kind of main shelveset.

**EDIT:**
Sorry I forgot to mention that we have been forbidden to use branches for this huge refactoring task. Really don't ask me why, I don't know. I just know that it is really stupid just as some of you mentioned because shelvesets are not suitable for such task. We are now searching for some way to manage this without branches somehow.

Comment: Maybe you should have considered a branch (or several) for this task. Using a shelveset for this is complicating things without any reason.

Answer (score 2):

You're using shelvesets incorrectly. Shelvesets are intended for short-term suspension of work by a single individual.

You should be using branches to isolate ongoing development work while maintaining an existing version.

Comment: Yes I know it is not suitable for it. I didn't mentioned that someone above me forbidden us to use branch for it. Don't ask me why, I really don't know and really think about his intelligence. We are now searching for way to do it without using branch which is naturally most suitable solution.

Comment: @Gondil Good luck. I'd love to understand the rationale behind not using the feature that is designed to solve the exact problem you're facing.